# Android Circle button background problems

Tags: android, photoshop

I have created circle button in photoshop. When I saved it in photoshop I deleted background box what was behind my button. And when I opened it with photoviewer there wasn't any background there was only a circle. But when I put ImageButton in Android then there is a white box. How can I remove this box behind my button?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android circle background becomes oval](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19063041/android-circle-background-becomes-oval)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be the default background. Try setting the `android:background` attribute to transparent.

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```