# Android circle background becomes oval

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to put a circle background on a textview. The circle becomes oval when its rendered.

My layout XML:

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/amount_key"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/circle"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:text="3\ndays"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="25dp" />


</LinearLayout>
```

My circle background:

```
<shape 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:shape="oval">

            <solid 
               android:color="#79bfea"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: You should set layout_weight and layout_height to fixed value i think. @sudhasri's solution below didn't work?

Comment: i did that, i overrided onMeasure by extending TextView to set width as height also

Answer (score 51, accepted):

- Change your `textView`'s `layout_height` and `layout_width` to `wrap_content`
- Add size tag inside shape tag as follows

> ```
> <shape 
> xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
> android:shape="oval">> 
> <solid android:color="#79bfea" />
> <size android:height="25dp"
>    android:width="25dp"/>
> </shape>
> ```

If it is still oval, try increasing the width and height in size tag. It worked for me!

Comment: In my case with `layout_height` and `layout_width` to `wrap_content` and adjusting the rigth padding made the trick.

Comment: @GueorguiObregon is the text centered?

Answer (score 18):

You can create your own Drawable which will constrain the radius to the min value between its width and height.

```
package com.example.android;

import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.ColorFilter;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;

public class ColorCircleDrawable extends Drawable {
    private final Paint mPaint;
    private int mRadius = 0;

    public ColorCircleDrawable(final int color) {
        this.mPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        this.mPaint.setColor(color);
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(final Canvas canvas) {
        final Rect bounds = getBounds();
        canvas.drawCircle(bounds.centerX(), bounds.centerY(), mRadius, mPaint);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBoundsChange(final Rect bounds) {
        super.onBoundsChange(bounds);
        mRadius = Math.min(bounds.width(), bounds.height()) / 2;
    }

    @Override
    public void setAlpha(final int alpha) {
        mPaint.setAlpha(alpha);
    }

    @Override
    public void setColorFilter(final ColorFilter cf) {
        mPaint.setColorFilter(cf);
    }

    @Override
    public int getOpacity() {
        return PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT;
    }
}
```

then apply to your textView:

```
textView.setBackground(new ColorCircleDrawable(Color.RED));
```

Comment: To get a ring instead of a filled circle use paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE) and paint.setStrokeWidth(strokeWidth).

Comment: Make sure to pass the color like this: int colorToUse = ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.my_color); textView.setBackground(new ColorCircleDrawable(colorToUse)); instead of textView.setBackground(new ColorCircleDrawable(R.color.my_color));

Answer (score 9):

To get this

[image]

I used two LinearLayout inside each other and set parent gravity to CENTER

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="80dp"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:baselineAligned="false"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="45dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/oval"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Text"
        android:textSize="12sp" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

and this is oval.xml inside drawable folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="#393939" />
    <size
        android:width="40dp"
        android:height="40dp" />
</shape>
```

without inner LinearLayout you'll get this

[image]

which it's code is

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="80dp"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:baselineAligned="false"
android:gravity="center"
android:background="@drawable/oval"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="Text"
    android:textSize="12sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

I extended TextView class to set width as height

```
public class TextViewSquareShaped extends TextView {


public TextViewSquareShaped(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init(attrs);
}

public TextViewSquareShaped(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(attrs);

}

public TextViewSquareShaped(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init(null);
}

private void init(AttributeSet attrs) {
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    int width = getDefaultSize(getSuggestedMinimumWidth(), widthMeasureSpec);
    setMeasuredDimension(width, width);
    Log.v("measure", "width:" + width + " height:" + width);
 }
}
```

And then combined with above Sudhasri's answer, I can show exact circular text view.

So no need to give fixed height and weight.

Comment: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: width and height must be > 0`

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using `match_parent` for width and height and setting drawable in background, so it will be oval. To achieve circle you can give same dimensions for width and height. NA dif want full screen then you can width from `java` code using `WindowManager` and set the same value in both width and height.

Answer (score -3):

try ring instead of oval

```
<shape 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="ring" >

    <solid android:color="#79bfea" />
</shape>
```