# Circle background for a imageview

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-drawable, android-image, android-shape

I am trying to place three image views with circle background. I have also placed a draw with round shape.

[image: preview]

But the background is not round shows oval.

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/contactphone"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/phonecall"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/contact_icon_round"
            android:layout_height="75dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/contactemail"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/mail"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/contact_icon_round"
            android:layout_height="75dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/contactlocation"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/location"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/contact_icon_round"
            android:layout_height="75dp" />
            android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Round Shape Drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="@color/white"/>
    <size android:width="5dp" android:height="5dp"/>
</shape>
```

There is something wrong but not able to figure out the mistake?

Thanks!

Comment: give your image views exact width and height instead of wrap_content

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android circle background becomes oval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19063041/android-circle-background-becomes-oval)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of this layout,

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="15dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    >

  <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:layout_height="75dp"
      >
  <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/contactphone"
      android:layout_width="75dp"
      android:src="@drawable/phonecall"
      android:layout_margin="10dp"
      android:background="@drawable/contact_icon_round"
      android:layout_height="75dp" />
  </LinearLayout>
  <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:layout_height="75dp"
      >
  <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/contactemail"
      android:layout_width="75dp"
      android:src="@drawable/mail"
      android:layout_margin="10dp"
      android:background="@drawable/contact_icon_round"
      android:layout_height="75dp" />
  </LinearLayout>
  <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:layout_height="75dp"
      >
  <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/contactlocation"
      android:layout_width="75dp"
      android:src="@drawable/location"
      android:layout_margin="10dp"
      android:background="@drawable/contact_icon_round"
      android:layout_height="75dp" />
  </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Background is shown as oval because of the uneven width and height.

Hope it may help you.

Comment: This solution is ok, but will not scale consistently for the range of screen densities for Android devices (xhdpi->xxxhdpi). Yes, you can address it by using values for the respective sizes, but it involves trial an error to make them look consistent.

Answer (score 1):

As long as your image sources are a perfect square, you can change the `android:layout_height` attribute of all `Image`s to `wrap_content`.
This way you can still use the `weight` behaviour.

Otherwise you have to use a fixed and equal width and height and remove the weight attributes...

Answer (score 1):

To paint a circular yellow background with a 2-pixel black border behind a circular imageView *without XML*:

```
GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable();
gd.setColor(Color.YELLOW);          // (no gradient)
gd.setStroke(2, Color.BLACK);
gd.setShape(GradientDrawable.OVAL);
gd.setGradientType(GradientDrawable.RADIAL_GRADIENT);
gd.setGradientRadius(iv.getWidth()/2);
iv.setBackground(gd);
```